# urllib request fails when page takes too long to respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib

I have a simple function (in python 3) to take a url and attempt to resolve it: printing an error code if there is one (e.g. 404) or resolve one of the shortened urls to its full url. My urls are in one column of a csv files and the output is saved in the next column. The problem arises where the program encounters a url where the server takes too long to respond- the program just crashes. Is there a simple way to force urllib to print an error code if the server is taking too long. I looked into [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) but that looks a little too complicated as i am just starting out. Any suggestions?

i.e. (COL A) shorturl  (COL B) http://deals.ebay.com/500276625

```
def urlparse(urlColumnElem):
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(urlColumnElem)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return (e.code)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        return ('URL_Error')
    else:
        redirect=conn.geturl()
        #check redirect
        if(redirect == urlColumnElem):
            #print ("same: ")
            #print(redirect)
            return (redirect)
        else:
            #print("Not the same url ")
            return(redirect)
```

EDIT: if anyone gets the http.client.disconnected error (like me), see this question/answer [http.client.RemoteDisconnected error while reading/parsing a list of URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676939/http-client-remotedisconnected-error-while-reading-parsing-a-list-of-urls)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> ```
> urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None[, timeout])
> ```
>
> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used).

You can set a realistic `timeout` (in seconds) for your process:

```
conn = urllib.request.urlopen(urlColumnElem, timeout=realistic_timeout_in_seconds)
```

and in order for your code to stop crushing, move everything inside the `try except` block:

```
import socket

def urlparse(urlColumnElem):
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(
                   urlColumnElem, 
                   timeout=realistic_timeout_in_seconds
               )
        redirect=conn.geturl()
        #check redirect
        if(redirect == urlColumnElem):
            #print ("same: ")
            #print(redirect)
            return (redirect)
        else:
            #print("Not the same url ")
            return(redirect)

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return (e.code)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        return ('URL_Error')
    except socket.timeout as e:
        return ('Connection timeout')
```

Now if a timeout occurs, you will catch the exception and the program will not crush.

Good luck :)

Comment: That partially works, however i just get a timeout error and the program quits, instead of waiting for much longer. 142
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
socket.timeout: timed out

Comment: I have updated my answer, the timeout raises a `socket.timeout` exception

Comment: Yep, i got there two by combining the answer from the bottom. For any beginner, also needs the import socket line for it to work Thanks!

Comment: No problem mate :), I will update the answer to the begginer friendly suggestion you made!

Comment: Thanks! I am from the world of C where writing something like this would take me a week without a 3 party library!

Comment: Good luck in your python adventures :)

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work! it now throws a http client remote disconnected error. Do I just add that as an exception? I am trying to dive into the deep end, don't quite understand how the more advanced functions work yet

Comment: That is a different issue, you should open a new question in SO if you don't find a good solution by yourself... Have a starting point here https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.RemoteDisconnected

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a timeout parameter than can be used to control the time allowed for `urlopen`. Next an timeout in `urlopen` should just throw an exception, more precisely a `socket.timeout`. If you do not want it to abort the program, you just have to catch it:

```
def urlparse(urlColumnElem, timeout=5):   # allow 5 seconds by default
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(urlColumnElem, timeout = timeout)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return (e.code)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        return ('URL_Error')
    except socket.timeout:
        return ('Timeout')
    else:
        ...
```